# Copying a SSH public key on a VPS with a SSH connection

Tags: vps, xclip

I am trying to copy my public key on a VPS.

After I connect I run the following

```
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Xclip gives me a can't open display error.

Right now I manually open the file and copy the key. There has to be a better, faster way to do this.

Comment: Headless servers don't have a clipboard which xclip could access. And even if they had one, the data would go to the server's clipboard and not the one on your client machine, which I guess is what you want. Use e.g. `scp` instead to copy files from a remote server to your local machine or another server directly over ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way copy  pub key to remote host is use ssh-copy-id:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host
```